# What is the name of the planet designing company in Hitchiker's Guide?

Tags: the-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-galaxy, douglas-adams

What is the name of the company that designs planets in *Hitchiker's Guide to the Galaxy*, or does it ever say?

The one which Slartibartfast works for.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't think we are ever given a 'company' name.

The planet that is the home to "custom-made luxury planet building" is called Magrathea.  However we are not told how it is organized economically.  It becomes the richest planet in the galaxy, but it may be that there are several corporations that operate from it, or none.

Comment: `I don't think we are ever given a 'company' name`. The recorded threat which is played to them comes the closest when it says `"This is a recorded announcement," it said, "as I'm afraid we're all out at the moment. The commercial council of Magrathea thanks you for your esteemed visit ..."`

Comment: @CrowTRobot. Its a good point and perhaps I'll add it to the answer, but the "commercial council" sounds a little like a grouping of separate companies that share common interests - in this case "defense".

Answer (score -3):

It's Slartibartfast, who designed Norway :) He even got a prize for it :)

Comment: The guy's name is Slartibartfast, and and he's an employee of the planet building organisation.  He's definitely not in charge.

Comment: Well, at least now I know his real name, wasn't sure how to spell it...

Comment: Well, I wanted to answer the question, but seems like my answer was wrong. But I learned something new from Christi's comment.